# Number Generator- two separate values

Tags: javascript, html

So stuck a little bit here,
I'm trying to create a random number generator that generates two different numbers besides one another from 1-6, for example: `Dice Roll is "1" "6"`. I created two different vars that generate from 1-6 thinking both would display but is not? What am I doing wrong?

My code is

```js
function myFunction() {
    var p = document.getElementById("mydata"); // get the paragraph
    var result = Math.floor( Math.random() * 7);
    var result2 = Math.floor( Math.random() * 7);
    p.innerHTML = "Dice rolls are " + result +result2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> Task 4 </title>
      <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="task4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- Create a paragraph with id mydata -->
      <div id="box">
      <p id="mydata">Roll Dice  </p>
    
      <!--Create a roll dice button-->
        <p> <button  onclick="myFunction();"> Roll Dice </button></p>  
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want it so that it displays like this instead of a sum 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apBI9.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work, just one small issue, with your current code, you can actually get 0, which doesn't make sense. Here is the code you would need to actually accomplish what you are looking for. Also, I changed it so that the min and max could be used with parameters.

```js
function rollDices(min, max) {
    var p = document.getElementById("mydata");
    var result1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    var result2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    p.innerHTML = "Dice rolls are \"" + result1 + "\" \"" + result2 + "\"";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> Task 4 </title>
      <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="task4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- Create a paragraph with id mydata -->
      <div id="box">
      <p id="mydata">Roll Dice  </p>
    
      <!--Create a roll dice button-->
        <p> <button  onclick="rollDices(1,6);"> Roll Dice </button></p>  
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The end result will be: Dice rolls are "X" "Y".

Answer (score 0):

It does work. Try opening devtools and disabling cache or switch your script tag to

  `<script src="task4.js?version=2" type="text/javascript"></script>`

EDIT: 
It's not displaying the sum. It's just displaying the numbers side by side.
You just need to add the quotes with string concatenation. E.g.

```js
window.rollDice = _ => {
    const rnd = _ => ~~(Math.random() * 7)
    document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML = `Dice rolls are "${rnd()}" "${rnd()}"`
}
```

```css
*{font-family:futura,helvetica !important;text-transform:uppercase;}body{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#42e695 0,#3bb2b8 100%);background-repeat:no-repeat;height:100vh;width:100%;padding:2px}button{font-size: 1rem;transition:all 500ms ease-out;display:inline-flex; margin: 5px;background:#FAFAFA;padding:20px;border-radius:5px;box-shadow:0 20px 50px -10px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}p{font-size:2rem;color:#fff;text-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}button:focus{outline:none;transform:rotate(360deg);cursor:pointer;}button.active{filter:invert(100%)}.months{display:flex;flex-direction: column wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:flex-start;align-items: flex-end;}p{color:white;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> Task 4 </title>
      <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="task4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- Create a paragraph with id mydata -->
      <div id="box">
      <p id="mydata">Roll Dice</p>
    
      <!--Create a roll dice button-->
        <p> <button id="diceroller" onclick="rollDice();"> Roll Dice </button></p>  
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

"from 1-6 thinking both would display but is not?"

Other answers aren't really addressing what you have stated as the problem.

So, it seems to be working fine for me.

However, if you open the inspector (Ctrl + Shift + I for chrome) and click on the "Console" tab. It may reveal whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String.format = function () {
        if (arguments.length == 0)
            return null;

        var str = arguments[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var re = new RegExp('\\{' + (i - 1) + '\\}', 'gm');
            str = str.replace(re, arguments[i]);
        }
        return str;
    }
```

try this code

`String.format("Dice rolls are {0} and {1}", result, result2);`

And to avoid 0 in roll result, you can use:
`var result = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6) + 1`

Answer (score -2):

p.innerHTML = "Dice rolls are " + result +result2;

-> p.innerHTML = "Dice rolls are " + result + result2;

Comment: Please explain in more detail.